# Is reference being reseated here or something else

Tags: c++, reference

Today I came to know that references are not [reseatable](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/reseating-refs.html)
Consider the code:

```
map<int,int> z;
z.insert(make_pair(1,2));
z.insert(make_pair(3,5));
z.insert(make_pair(4,6));
auto ref = z.at(1);
ref = z.at(3);
```

`std::map::at` returns a *reference to the mapped value of the requested element*, implies ref is a reference. Why is it allowed to be reassigned(as references cannot be re-binded). What is happening here.

Comment: "Returning a reference" doesn't mean what you think.

Comment: @KerrekSB what does it mean then. Any pointers to read from or could you please elaborate.

Comment: It is as I said in my answer: The result of the function call is an lvalue. It's OK to say "returns a reference" colloquially if you know what it means, but it still returns an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto` doesn't make reference types. The expression `z.at(1)` is an lvalue of type `int`, so `ref` is also an int.

(If you wanted a reference, you'd have to say `auto &` or `auto &&` (or in C++14 `decltype(auto)`).)

Comment: so if I have `map<int, vector<int>>` then it will just make copy of whole vector?

Comment: I have lots of changes to make..:(

Comment: I just tried `auto &ref` instead of `auto ref` but it didn't give any error.

Comment: Why should it? You have initialized a reference, then assigned a new value to the element it refers to. Consider: `int a; int& r = a; r = 42;`. The last statement is equivalent to `a = 42;`. That's the whole point of references.

Comment: If a function returns int& and I store this in an auto, the type of the auto is int and not int&?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik understood.

Comment: @NeilKirk: That's dangerous talk. Don't say it like that. Say, "the return type of the function is `int&`, so the function evaluates as an lvalue of type `int`".

Comment: I don't see what is dangerous about my question?

Comment: @NeilKirk: They danger when you say that "the function returns an int&" is that you confuse yourself about what `auto` will deduce. The value of the function evaluation is of type `int`, and so `auto` deduces `int`.

Comment: If r1 is type int&, what is the type of r2 in auto r2 = r1?